# How to create custom Chat (Conversational) Bot for consumer or enterprise using Kore's Bot Builder?

Tags: chat, bots, chatbot

I have tried building my own bot using [Kore Bot Builder](https://app.kore.com/bt) to replicate the ["Every bank does digital. Do it better."](https://kore.com/use-cases/#customers) use case.

Till now, what I could do with my bot is, deliver alerts and execute actions in form of tasks.

What I want now is, a Siri-like conversational experience, tailored to my business need. Here is an example of SAP HANA bot as shown in this [video](https://youtu.be/0cdQWGJhJEw?t=1m1s).